# Need to parse JSON string with value is quoted curly braces

Tags: javascript, json

I need to parse JSON string.

I've tried `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse` below sample string, but server performed escape sequencing

I used `str.replace('/\\/g','')` to remove the escape sequence but that doesnt help because if you look in the `"default_request"` key is wraps its value with `""` which is doesnt allow me parse it using `JSON.parse()`

```
    {
      "request": {
        "service_name": "authService",
        "url": "https://some-url.com/{accounts}",
        "default_request": "{\"authMethod\":\"somename\",\"multiCheck\":false}"
        }
    }
```

so I tried to replace `"{` with `{` and  `}"`  with `}`

```
str.replace('/"{/g','{')).replace('/}"/g','}'))
```

but it creates another problem.

```
Favourable condition
    {
      "request": {
       "service_name": "authService",
       "url": "https://some-url.com/{accounts}",
       "default_request": {\"authMethod\":\"somename\",\"multiCheck\":false}
      }
    }
```

Comment: _"key is wraps its value with "" which is doesnt allow me parse it using JSON.parse()"_ - Why? That's exactly what JSON looks like...

Comment: `jsonObject` is a misleading name because [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). The content is an object. And one of its properties (`request.default_request`) is JSON.

Comment: the value of `default_request` (`"{\"authMethod\":\"somename\",\"multiCheck\":false}"`) is itself JSON.

Comment: `jsonObject ` is the some `const` i use i'll change the name in the question.

every time i parse the string it throws me error at the `  SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position `

Comment: I'd ask the server folks if they can refrain from double-encoding the default_request property.

Comment: Thanks @james but this is for my personal project which uses the json response and its a  different team which manages it and they probably have some use case for double encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default_request was stringifyied twice. to fix it, try this

```
jsonObject.request.default_request = JSON.parse(jsonObject.request.default_request);
```